# what does this mean {fseek (inptr, - ( bi.biWidth * 3 + padding), SEEK_CUR);} in the program that resizes a bmp image?

Tags: c, image-resizing, bmp

I don't quite understand the necessity of this code here.

```
// skip over padding, if any
fseek(inptr, padding, SEEK_CUR);

// then add it back (to demonstrate how)
for (int k = 0; k < new_padding; k++)
{
    fputc(0x00, outptr);
}

if (repeat < n - 1)
{
    fseek(inptr, - (bi.biWidth * 3 + padding), SEEK_CUR);
}
```

Comment: Do not post links to the code.  Rather, copy/paste the code into the question itself.  Because 1) outside links can move/disappear. 2) the linked code is (as this linked code is) unreadable and 3) when there is a problem, we cannot (easily) reproduce the problem code from an image

Comment: a bit of background:  the lines of pixels on an image must be a multiple of 2 bytes.  Therefore, there is often some padding bytes at the end of each line of pixels.  The last `if()` code block is assuming that each pixel is 3 bytes (not always a valid assumption as the width of a pixel can be anywhere from 1 to 4 bytes, consistent within the image, but can be different in a different image)

Comment: the last `if()` code block is stepping back to the beginning of the current row of pixels in the image

Comment: The line in the question: it seeks one scanline back.

Comment: @ Tony To enter a code block by hand, start with a blank line, and start each line of code with four spaces. Or the easy way: copy the code from your editor, paste it here, select it, and click the code button `{}` which is at the top of the edit box.

Comment: [Each line of pixel data in a BMP must be a multiple of 4 bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Pixel_storage). So if you change the number of pixels on a line, you may also need to change the padding. Note: you haven't actually shown the code that duplicates pixels, but I'm assuming that's what the code does.

Comment: It is a very clunky way to rescale a 24bpp BMP image file vertically.  Done by writing the same line in original image repeatedly to the output file.  It looks merely like example code, not generally useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to confirm the correctness or even the pertinence of this code fragment without the full context.

`fseek` moves the input stream's pointer forward by `padding` bytes.

The program then outputs `new_padding` null bytes to the output stream, presumably a different amount from `padding`. Microsoft's BMP file format requires some padding in various places, for easier reading into memory.

Finally, `fseek` is used again to set the input stream pointer backward to the beginning of the row of pixels (3 bytes per pixel) plus the padding it skipped, but only if `(repeat < n - 1)`.